# combinations from character string

Tags: r, combinations, stringr

I am testing a number of models and want to create an output string of all possible combinations of an input string as long as the letters aren't repeated. As an example:

```
inputdata <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3")
```

The output would look like:

```
  outputdata <- c("A1 + B1 + C1", "A2 + B1 + C1","A3 + B1 + C1", "A1 + B2 + C1", "A1 + B3 + C1", "A1 + B1 + C2", "A1 + B1 + C3", "A2 + B2 + C1", "A2 + B2 + C2", "A3 + B2 + C2", "A3 + B3 + C2", "A3 + B3 + C3")
```

I've got most of the way there through this code:

```
  library(gtools)
  dataformodel <- data.frame(combinations(9,3,inputdata))
  dataformodel$x <- apply( dataformodel[, ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "+" )
  dataformodel <- dataformodel[, -c(1:3)]
```

The issue here being that same letters are repeated eg. `"A1 + A2 + B1"` - my thought was to count unique letters within each string and remove where count < 3...but didn't have any luck (using the stingr package). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
split(inputdata, substr(inputdata,1,1))
# $A
# [1] "A1" "A2" "A3"
# $B
# [1] "B1" "B2" "B3"
# $C
# [1] "C1" "C2" "C3"
```

If we call `expand.grid` on this, we can it'll give us each combination of each `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```
head( do.call(expand.grid, split(x, substr(x,1,1))) )
#    A  B  C
# 1 A1 B1 C1
# 2 A2 B1 C1
# 3 A3 B1 C1
# 4 A1 B2 C1
# 5 A2 B2 C1
# 6 A3 B2 C1
```

Now we can just `paste(..., collapse="+")` this:

```
apply(do.call(expand.grid, split(x, substr(x,1,1))), 1, paste, collapse="+")
#  [1] "A1+B1+C1" "A2+B1+C1" "A3+B1+C1" "A1+B2+C1" "A2+B2+C1" "A3+B2+C1"
#  [7] "A1+B3+C1" "A2+B3+C1" "A3+B3+C1" "A1+B1+C2" "A2+B1+C2" "A3+B1+C2"
# [13] "A1+B2+C2" "A2+B2+C2" "A3+B2+C2" "A1+B3+C2" "A2+B3+C2" "A3+B3+C2"
# [19] "A1+B1+C3" "A2+B1+C3" "A3+B1+C3" "A1+B2+C3" "A2+B2+C3" "A3+B2+C3"
# [25] "A1+B3+C3" "A2+B3+C3" "A3+B3+C3"
```

Notes:

- if your data is large, then `expand.grid` may run out of memory;
- this is one of the few times when I think `apply` on a `data.frame` is safe and reasonable, since we know that all of its inputs are of the same class

Answer (score 3):

The 'dataformodel' can be `filter`ed to remove the rows that have same letter

```
dataformodel <- dataformodel[!apply(sapply(dataformodel, 
      sub, pattern = "\\d+", replacement = ""), 1, anyDuplicated),]
```

and then apply the OP's code to get the output

```
head(dataformodel)
#[1] "A1+B1+C1" "A1+B1+C2" "A1+B1+C3" "A1+B2+C1" "A1+B2+C2" "A1+B2+C3"
```

---

A faster approach would be using `RcppAlgos`

```
library(RcppAlgos)
dataformodel <-  comboGeneral(inputdata, m = 3, repetition = FALSE)
```